# Fgets isn't getting any input from stdin or stdin isn't being equaled to the input?

Tags: objective-c, console-application, fgets

Example code:

```
    char cnumb1[2];
    NSLog(@"Do you have an account already?(1 for Yes, 0 for no)");
    int c;
    //Flushes input
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    fgets(cnumb1, sizeof cnumb1, stdin);
    size_t length = strlen(cnumb1);
    if (cnumb1 [length-1] == '\n'){ // In case that the input string has 1 character plus '\n'
        cnumb1 [length-1] = '\0';} // Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false.
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: cnumb1];
    NSLog(@"string:%@", string);
```

With the input "0" (EDIT: For some reason, I need to press enter twice), I get the output "string:"
As far as I can tell, the stdin isn't being set correctly.
Also, the I started without the flush lines, but that caused lots of problems because I have more fgets later on and it the stdin would only be the initial input, so I added those.

Why isn't the input being set as stdin?
Or is it another problem entirely?

Comment: `char cnumb1[2]; fgets(cnumb1, 3, stdin);` - ***???***

Comment: Oh that was an error in the example code, sorry! I'll change that. Its not like that in the code normally. Sorry!

Comment: If you accept some advice: use `sizeof cnumb1` instead of hard-coded sizes.

Comment: Like fgets(cnumb1, sizeof cnumb1, stdin);  -?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: I'll edit it in and start doing it from now on. Thanks. It doesn't solve the main problem, but it is useful to know.

Comment: yes it's not a solution (that's why I posted a comment and not an answer), but you better get used to these conventions, because they ensure safety :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
while((c = get char()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

needs to go directly AFTER the fgets, not before.

Also, while not answering the question directly, its better to do

```
fgets(cnumb1, sizeof cnumb1, stdin);
```

then hardcode in the sizeof cnumb1, as @H2CO3 kindly pointed out to me.